# Best way to detect that code is running in InstallHandler context?

Tags: apex, managed-package, package-install, postinstall

Implementing an [InstallHandler](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_install_handler.htm) allows a managed package to execute setup Apex code on install or upgrade of the package.

I'd like to have some unrelated code - a trigger - behave differently for this install/upgrade case. A static Apex flag - set at the start of the `InstallHandler` implementation - is the first thing that comes to mind. But before I add that, is there any other mechanism already there to detect this context?

Comment: It will all run in the ghost user context. IIRC there are some tell tail markers that it is the ghost user, not a real user.

Comment: Hi @PhilW, But are any cleaner than the simple static?

Comment: Hmmm. I guess not.

Comment: I concur. There's no specific method that outright tells you about InstallHandler or SandboxPostCopy status (e.g. like System.isBatchable). You'll need to set a static variable instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for the record, consensus is an Apex static variable that the `InstallHandler` implementation sets and other code tests i.e.:

```
/**
 * Referenced by triggers.
 */
public inherited sharing class Triggers {
    
    /**
     * Want to special case logic related to install handlers: the InstallHandler
     * implementation can set this and other code e.g. trigger logic can check it
     */
    public static Boolean isInstallHandlerContext = false;

    ...
}
```